# Action for "Find in Files" in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: jetbrains-ide, ideavim

In JetBrains IDEs, `Main Menu | Edit | Find | Find in Files...`. On Mac it has <kbd>Cmd + Sift + F</kbd> shortcut.

Does anybody know what action it is? I could not find it in IntelliJ action list.

Comment: Try `FindInPath` (that's what "Find in Files..." used to be called in the past -- they have changed the name about 2 years ago or so). https://gist.github.com/zchee/9c78f91cc5ad771c1f5d

Comment: ALSO, from https://towardsdatascience.com/the-essential-ideavim-remaps-291d4cd3971b -- *"Use the `:actionlist` command to find the full action ID list."*

Comment: Great! @LazyOne , thank you very much! I've tried it and it works :)
...but why do so many people here put answers into a comment???
Is there something wrong with dropping an answer???

Comment: I'm not using IdeaVim and have no way of checking that it will work. What if JB made the change and it's now called FindInFiles or alike and that FindInPath with write a warning in the logs every time it is used etc?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `FindInPath` ("Find in Path" -- that's what "Find in Files" used to be called in the past; they have changed the name about 2 years ago or so).

Found the name here: https://gist.github.com/zchee/9c78f91cc5ad771c1f5d

Answer (score 0):

IdeaVIM has a feature to display action IDs as you do things. See the section [Finding action ids](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#executing-ide-actions) in the IdeaVim README for details on how to use that.

If for some reason that doesn't work, I've come up with another way to find action names to use in IdeaVIM key bindings (or anywhere else you need the action name). Here is the process:

1. Go to IntelliJ settings and open the Keymap settings.
2. Use the search bar to find the action.
3. Right-click (or ⌃-click) on the action and choose "Add Abbreviation".
4. Type in a string that's unlikely to be used anywhere else. I use "zjzjzj".
5. Click OK to close settings and save to disk.
6. Open up your IntelliJ Configuration directory. This is `idea.config.path` on the page [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs). Currently on my machine it is "~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2" but it depends on your OS and IntelliJ version.
7. Open up the file `options/abbrevs.xml` in a text editor.
8. Search for the string you used in Step 4, e.g. "zjzjzj".
9. Now you'll see the action id you're looking for. Example below.
10. Clean up by removing the abbreviation in Settings→Keymap.

Example of what shows up in abbrevs.xml:

```xml
      <action id="FindInPath">
        <abbreviation name="zjzjzj" />
      </action>
```